# How to formalize the definition of likeness/similarity between relations in Coq?

Tags: logic, relation, coq

I am reading the book Introduction to Mathematics Philosophy by B.Russell and trying to formalize the definitions. Whereas I got stuck on proving the equivalence between the two definitions of similarity posed in the book.

Here are the text quoted from the book. ([context](http://people.umass.edu/klement/imp/imp.html#page54))

1) Defining similarity directly:

> We may define two relations P and Q as “similar,” or as having
>   “likeness,” when there is a one-one relation S whose domain is the
>   field of P and whose converse domain is the field of Q, and which is
>   such that, if one term has the relation P to another, the correlate of
>   the one has the relation Q to the correlate of the other, and vice
>   versa.

Here's my comprehension of the above text:

```
Inductive similar {X} (P : relation X) (Q : relation X) : Prop :=
  | similar_intro : forall (S : relation X),
      one_one S ->
      (forall x, field P x <-> domain S x) ->
      (forall x y z w, P x y -> S x z -> S y w -> Q z w) ->
      (forall x y z w, Q z w -> S x z -> S y w -> P x y) ->
      similar P Q.
```

2) Defining similarity through the concept of 'correlator':

> A relation S is said to be a “correlator” or an “ordinal correlator”
>   of two relations P and Q if S is one-one, has the field of Q for its
>   converse domain, and is such that P is the relative product of S and Q
>   and the converse of S.
>
> Two relations P and Q are said to be “similar,” or to have “likeness,”
>   when there is at least one correlator of P and Q.

My definition to this is:

```
Inductive correlator {X} (P Q : relation X) : relation X -> Prop :=
  | correlator_intro : forall (S : relation X),
      one_one S ->
      (forall x, field P x <-> domain S x) ->
      (forall x y, relative_product (relative_product S Q) (converse S) x y <-> P x y) ->
      correlator P Q S.

Inductive similar' {X} (P Q : relation X) : Prop :=
  | similar'_intro : forall S, correlator P Q S -> similar' P Q.
```

But I couldn't prove that `similar` is equivalent to `similar'`, where did I make the mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your first definition, is it ``forall x y z w, P x y -> S x z -> S y w -> Q z w`` or ``forall x y, P x y -> exists z w, S x z /\ S y w /\ Q z w`` ?

Comment: @Vinz Excuse me, I don't understand. In my definition it is `forall x y z w, P x y -> S x z -> S y w -> Q z w`. Do you mean it should be expressed as `forall x y, P x y -> exists z w, S x z /\ S y w /\ Q z w`?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if you got this definition correct (but then it's been a long time since I read this kind of formal definitions, I might be wrong)

Comment: @Vinz Hmm, but I think the existence of such `w` and `z` should be implied by the hypothesis `forall x, field P x <-> domain S x`.

Comment: It is difficult to help debug without all of your auxiliary definitions, including `relation`, `one_one`, and `relative_product`.